# Python ITK Rehsape error with median Filter

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, itk

I have the follwoing question. I have a numpy array with size 91x40x21 full of floats and I want to use the median filter. Unfortunatly when i trying to cast it back to an array i get this error:

"cannot reshape array of size 76440 into shape (0,0,0)"

This is my code:

```
image_view = itk.GetImageViewFromArray(matrix.astype('float32'))
medianImage = itk.MedianImageFilter.New(image_view, Radius = 3)
matrix = itk.GetArrayViewFromImage(medianImage)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you explicitely update and get output from the image, then everythink will work:

```
matrix = np.random.random_integers(0,100,(10,6,8))
image_view = itk.GetImageViewFromArray(matrix.astype('Float32'))
medianImageFilter = itk.MedianImageFilter.New(image_view, Radius = 3)
medianImageFilter.Update() 
medianImage = medianImageFilter.GetOutput()
newMatrix = itk.GetArrayViewFromImage(medianImage)
```